# ValueError: is not supported for tf version 2. See `model_builder.py` for centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have been trying to run object detection on TensorFlow, which to run on Windows with the GPU is very troublesome using an older version of Python 3.10.0 and tensorflow2.10 & tensorflow-gpu2.10.0

So initially I have it working on SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320

since the video feed I am trying to work on is 2k output as it comes from a VR headset,

I needed more speed to resolve the frames much quicker and with higher accuracy,
So I opted to change the model to: CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN Keypoints 512x512

And after a plethora of errors I worked through, I finally got it to the training stage and could not find a simple answer or go around to solving this.

This is my Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in 
tf.compat.v1.app.run()
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main
model_lib_v2.train_loop(
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 547, in train_loop
detection_model = MODEL_BUILD_UTIL_MAP['detection_model_fn_base'](
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 1262, in build
return build_func(getattr(model_config, meta_architecture), is_training,
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 412, in _build_ssd_model
_check_feature_extractor_exists(ssd_config.feature_extractor.type)
File "C:\Users\Simulator\TFOD_GPU\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 270, in _check_feature_extractor_exists
raise ValueError(
ValueError:  is not supported for tf version 2. See `model_builder.py` for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow

I tried using the other file model_main.py, to see if it might tell me something else and threw the same error.
I rechecked with the verification script model_builder_tf2_test.py and I got OK (skipped=1) which means it should be ok, but with no avail same error comes through.

So I am confused about how to move on.